# This isn't changing the position of the paddles in Pong

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle, pong

this is the Code I wrote; Not sure what I did wrong here. When you press W and S the left paddle should go Up and down, and a and d should work for the other paddle. I'm currently just following a tutorial online, and I've already hit a wall. I just can't for the life of me see what's wrong with this; unless if python doesn't allow variables to be put into the function like this

```
import turtle

#window set up
wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.title = ("Main Test")
wn.bgcolor("black")
wn.setup(width=800, height=600)
wn.tracer = 0

#paddleA

paddleA = turtle.Turtle()
paddleA.speed(0)
paddleA.shape("square")
paddleA.color("white")
paddleA.shapesize(stretch_wid=5, stretch_len= 1)
paddleA.penup()
paddleA.goto(-350,0)

#paddleB

paddleB = turtle.Turtle()
paddleB.speed(0)
paddleB.shape("square")
paddleB.color("white")
paddleB.shapesize(stretch_wid=5, stretch_len= 1)
paddleB.penup()
paddleB.goto(350,0)

#ball

ball = turtle.Turtle()
ball.speed(0)
ball.shape("circle")
ball.color("white")
ball.penup()
ball.goto(0,0)

#function
def paddle(paddle, dir):
    y = paddle.ycor()
    y += 20 * dir
    paddle.sety(y)

#Keyboard Binding

wn.listen()
wn.onkeypress(paddle(paddleA, 1), "w")
wn.onkeypress(paddle(paddleA, -1), "s")
wn.onkeypress(paddle(paddleB, 1), "a")
wn.onkeypress(paddle(paddleB, -1), "d")

#Main Game Loop
while True:
    wn.update()
```

Comment: You have not told us what happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`onkeypress`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.onkeypress) requires:

> a *function* with no arguments or `None`

as the first parameter. You are effectively passing `None` as that's what a *function call* evaluates to. You can see that for yourself by executing:

```
print(type(paddle(paddleA, 1)))
```

A function *call* is not a function!

---

One way to get around this is to wrap your function call into an anonymous function using `lambda`, like so:

```
wn.listen()
wn.onkeypress(lambda: paddle(paddleA, 1), "w")
wn.onkeypress(lambda: paddle(paddleA, -1), "s")
wn.onkeypress(lambda: paddle(paddleB, 1), "a")
wn.onkeypress(lambda: paddle(paddleB, -1), "d")
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to @JanezKuhar's `lambda` solution (+1), is to use the `partial` function from the **functools** library.  Here's an example implementation that eliminates the `paddle()` function by wrapping paddle methods:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from functools import partial

# Window set up
screen = Screen()
screen.setup(width=800, height=600)
screen.title = ("Main Test")
screen.bgcolor('black')

# Paddle A

paddleA = Turtle()
paddleA.speed('fastest')
paddleA.shape('square')
paddleA.color('white')
paddleA.shapesize(stretch_len=5)
paddleA.setheading(90)
paddleA.penup()
paddleA.setx(-350)

# Paddle B

paddleB = paddleA.clone()
paddleB.setx(350)

# Ball

ball = Turtle()
ball.speed('fastest')
ball.shape('circle')
ball.color('white')
ball.penup()

# Keyboard Binding

screen.onkeypress(partial(paddleA.forward, 20), 'w')
screen.onkeypress(partial(paddleA.backward, 20), 's')
screen.onkeypress(partial(paddleB.forward, 20), 'a')
screen.onkeypress(partial(paddleB.backward, 20), 'd')

screen.listen()
screen.mainloop()
```

Note that I've stretched your paddles in the other direction and rotated them so that we can use either `forward(20)` or `backward(20)` to move them instead of the combination of `sety(ycor() + 20)`